# Why is the total force at a free surface zero?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, boundary-conditions

I am looking into waves on a free surface for which their are two main conditions:

- Kinematic condition: Particles on the surface remain on the surface.
- Dynamic condition: Forces acting on the surface are in equilibrium.

Where do these conditions come from?

**Reference**

- [Here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Y_utl_LspVcC&pg=PA708&dq=pressure%20equal%20at%20a%20free%20surface&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimo9zy547PAhXpA8AKHYmSC5AQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=pressure%20equal%20at%20a%20free%20surface&f=false) (link to Google Books)
- And [here](https://uwaterloo.ca/applied-mathematics/current-undergraduates/continuum-and-fluid-mechanics-students/amath-463-students/surface-gravity-waves)

Comment: The very surface is infinitely thin and has no mass.

Comment: If there is a net force on a free surface, it would respond to the force and move, resulting in zero net force.

Answer (score 0):

The so called kinematic condition is essentially an equivalence between Eulerian and Lagrangian descriptions of a fluid. Consider a particle on the surface located at $\vec{x}$. Furthermore, for an irrotaional inviscid fluid the body of the fluid obeys Laplace's equation which means there exists a velocity potential $\phi$. The first condition is:

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \phi_z \quad @z=\eta$$
where $d/dt$ is the total derivative, $\phi$ is the velocity potential. Now, if we parametrize all points on the surface as a function $\eta(\vec{x}(t),t)$ then by definition 
$$\frac{d\eta}{dt}  = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}+\nabla\phi\cdot \nabla \eta = \phi_z$$ 
evaluated at $z=\eta$.

Secondly, one has the dynamic boundary condition (Let's just do this for gravity waves and ignore things like capillarity). This is the statement that pressure is continuous across the interface (do you know why we do this?). To get this, we begin with Euler's equations: 
$$\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\nabla\vec{u} =-\nabla p +g\hat{z}.$$

The advective term can be rewritten as 
$$\vec{u}\nabla\vec{u}= \frac{1}{2}\nabla (\vec{u}\cdot \vec{u}) -\vec{u}\times \vec{\omega}$$
with $\vec{\omega} = \nabla \times \vec{u}$ the vorticity, identically zero for our flow. Therefore one can rewrite the Euler equations at the surface as
$$\nabla ( \phi_t+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2 +g z+p)=0$$
as $z=\eta$
Hence, at the surface ($z=\eta)$ we have 
$$\phi_t+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2 +g z+p=B(t)$$
for some constant $B(t)$. Usually, in the absence of forcing we set $p=0$ at the surface.

Comment: The first equation is wrong (a vector equals a scalar). Did you mean $\dfrac{d\vec{x}}{d t}\cdot \vec{e}_z=\partial_z \phi$? I understand the second equation but I don't see how it proves the kinematic condition. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @anderstood Yes, that was a typo. What do you means "proves the kinematic criterion"? It simply states that particles at the surface stay at the surface.

Comment: The point I don't understand is whether the fact that "particles at the surface remain at the surface" is an additional assumption, or a consequence of the previous assumptions (potential flow).

Comment: It's a kinematic implication of your definitions. It is not an additional assumption. You are defining a curve $\eta$, a locus of fluid particles, such that it's evolution $d\eta/dt$ (total derivative) is exactly equal to the vertical fluid velocity at that point, hence these particles remain at the surface, by definition.